# How do you minimize Age of Empires 3 on mac?

Tags: macos, age-of-empires-iii

Is there any way to minimize the game when it is in fullscreen?
Or change to another app..
Every time I need to go to another app i need to go to Options -> Graphics -> Windowed Mode -> Apply.

Is there any keyboard or mouse shortcut?

Already tried this with no success:

- CMD + TAB
- CMD + H
- CMD + M

Any suggestions will be tested

Comment: Have you tried alt+tab? Apparently, you can use it to switch between virtual desktops in OSX.

Comment: @Nolonar alt+tab switches between apps just like Windows